# Creature with equipment attached is returned to owner's hand

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature has equipment attached, what happens to the equipment if this creature is returned to the owner's hand?

Does it:

- Return to the owner's hand as well?
- Go to the graveyard?
- Remain on the battlefield?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will remain on the battlefield.

> **301.5c** ... An Equipment that equips an illegal or nonexistent permanent becomes unattached from that permanent but remains on the battlefield. ...

Comment: How can you attach it to another creature?

Comment: @rahmu You can use Brass Squire's tap ability to re-attach the equipment to another creature.

Comment: @rahmu That is a new question, you can ask it by clicking the Ask question button on the top of the page.